# Trying To Pass An Array Of Values To Search Using "IN"

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a simple access query stored within Access and it does not seem to work. The query is this...

```
SELECT blah FROM table WHERE (((tableID) IN ([@myArrayOfIDs])));
```

Pretty simple but of course it just does not want to work? If I write IN (16,17,21) then the result is returned correctly but the way I have it now, nothing comes back at all. What am I missing?

Edit: I convert the array into a string of comma separated values using VB.NET before passing it to Access.

Comment: If you're accessing this database from a VB.NET app then why not just build the SELECT statement in VB.NET (using the string of comma-separated values you've already generated) and execute it?

Comment: In Access the square brackets are going to consider everything in between as a single string, not multiple values.  If this could work it will only work like IN (16, 17, 18) or IN ([16], [17], [18] )

Answer (score 1):

All you are getting is IN(['16,17,21']), it is not testing for the individual numbers. I don't recall Access supporting multiple variable number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The Access db engine will not accept a parameter for the `IN` value list.  IOW, something like this will never work ...

```
tableID IN ([a_parameter_string])
```

You would need to dynamically create the SQL statement and insert your string of comma-separated values into the SQL statement text.

Or you could do something like this instead ...

```
"," & [a_parameter_string] & "," Like "%," & tableID & ",%"
```

But that one seems ugly and will not be able to use indexed retrieval to speed up the query.

Comment: I've changed my Data Access Layer to allow me to pass command text as well as stored procedure names now so I will give it a shot and mark as the answer if it work (which I'm confident in your response). Thanks for the help!